# How to create two divs side-by-side with one extending till page width?

Tags: html, css

What I need is two divs in following fashion:

> [-width-of-content-][------------------remaining-width-of-page----------------------------]

I remember how in olden days it was a breeze to do this by using tables. But now tables are taboo, so how do I achieve this with div? I have been spending hours trying to figure this one out!

```
<div style='float:left;display:inline-block'> Hello</div>
<div style='float:left;width:100%''> THIS DIV BREAKS</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to float the left element.

HTML

```
<div id="left">Hello yoyoyoy jrllo hello blah blah</div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

CSS

```
#left,#right{
    height:50px;
}

#left{
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

#right{
    background:green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qb3374ou/

EDIT: right div with content.. same result
https://jsfiddle.net/qb3374ou/1/

Comment: The problem with this is that when I type anything on the right div, then its right aligned as well...I want it right after the content of the left div...

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not understanding your problem, could you be more specific, or draw another diagram.  Are you talking about the text inside the right div? Because that text is left aligned, appearing right after the left div text.

Answer (score 2):

You could also achieve this using flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/yr05wkuh/1/

This would keep your DIVs the same height, without requiring you to set a value.

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.div1{
    background-color:yellow;
}

.div2{
    flex: 1 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"> Hello</div>
    <div class="div2"> THIS DIV BREAKS</div>
</div>
```

Here's a good resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

two divs side-by-side is impossible but this might work:

```
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                               width of content
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                     Remaining width of page
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
```

hope it helped.. .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro,.. my mistake... this one is more working :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Width of content</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Remaining Pages</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but I think you're trying to get this:

HTML:

```
<div class="right">Text goes here</div>
<div class="left">Text for the left div goes here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right {
    float:right;
    background: #ddd;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    }

.left {
    background-color:#ccc;
    height: 100px;
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veW2z/88/

Answer (score -1):

Actually,"col-md-" are the classes of Bootstrap ..u need to include the Bootstrap css to make it work..Here is the link  for it[enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)

```
           This contain complete Bootstrap but u need to include only the css in it and write the code
```