# HTML side by side divs, while one has fixed width and the second one fits remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have that code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div style="background-color:rgb(150,200,255); margin:3px ; height:50px; width:100%px">
    <font size=6> <center> <b> 123123123123123123123123 </b> </center></font>

</div>

<div style="background-color:rgb(180,215,255); display: inline-block; float:left; width:300px; height:90vh; " >
    aasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
    <ol>
    <li> 11111111 </li>
    <li> 222222222222222222222222222222 </li>
    <li> 3333333333333333 </li>
</div>

<div style="float:left; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
    aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa 

</div>
```

It looks good.
http://i.cubeupload.com/yOz2zu.png
However if i add more words to the third div, it goes down.
http://i.cubeupload.com/pZ65dr.png
Is there any way to make div not going down without adding fixed width? I want to have only the first div with fixed width, the second one has to fill. I don't want to use JS. Thanks for help.

Comment: width:100%px.  That is invalid and will likely fail everything after it.

Comment: Tip #1, stop using `<font>` and `<center>`. They were deprecated ages ago and not part of HTML5.

Comment: why should I if they still work?

Comment: that width:100%px was just a typo while i tried in many ways to fix it and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Your same exact question was asked an hour ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877155/how-to-create-two-divs-side-by-side-with-one-extending-till-page-width/33877285#33877285

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to float one of the div tags.  You can also get rid of the table style display CSS.  As other comments have mentioned, you don't want to use `<font>` and `<center>` tags.  They are depricated and no longer supported.

```
<div style="background-color:rgb(150,200,255); margin:3px ; height:50px; width:100%;">
    <b> 123123123123123123123123 </b>

</div>

<div style="background-color:rgb(180,215,255); display: inline-block; float:left; width:300px; height:90px;">
    aasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
    <ol>
        <li> 11111111 </li>
        <li> 222222222222222222222222222222 </li>
        <li> 3333333333333333 </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div>
    aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa 
    aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa 
    aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa 
    aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa 
    aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa 

</div>
```

Comment: If font and center still work, and they do their job well, why should i stop using them? What should i use instead?

Comment: @MarioPL98 because it *doesn't* work across all browsers.  Theres some good reading on it here: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/character_famsupp_92.html and here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: Of course for longer paragraphs i use css formatting. According to w3, font tag is still supported in all most popular browsers.

Comment: @MarioPL98 W3 says that `<font>` is depricated and should not be used.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT  and  https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font

Comment: Some browsers still support it, but not all.  Since it doesn't work for all users, it does not work.  W3 is very clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally put all my style in CSS

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color:rgb(150, 200, 255);
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    background-color:rgb(180, 215, 255);
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height: 90vh;
}
.content {
    float:right;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

```html
  

<div class="header">123123123123123123123123</div>
<div class="left">aasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
    <ul>
        <li>11111111</li>
        <li>222222222222222222222222222222</li>
        <li>3333333333333333</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent id nisi ultrices, egestas erat vitae, laoreet lorem. Suspendisse sed mi placerat dolor lacinia maximus. Nullam sem tellus, facilisis sed tristique in, faucibus eu ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris sed ex id ipsum pharetra dignissim. Donec vitae pulvinar est. Suspendisse placerat turpis vel arcu semper vulputate. Cras laoreet purus ac facilisis sodales. Vestibulum blandit, justo sed porta bibendum, lectus nisi rhoncus tortor, quis dapibus urna nulla et nibh.</div>
```

Comment: That's actually a homework and it's unnecessary to make more files. Of course while making a real webpage, I would use external css.